# Кнопка присутствующая на превью, отсутствует по факту

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image: Предпросмотр]

Так выглядит предпросмотр, тест на моем телефоне показывает всё, кроме кнопки `Suggest`.

Я не очень опытен в `UI` верстке, если и полетят помидоры - до желательно с примером, как будет "правильно", иначе просто можете проигнорировать этот пункт, мне известно, что можно было сделать лучше - вот только не знаю как.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/form_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_entry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="Some text">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Some text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/relation_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="Relation type">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/text_input_entry"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:entries="@array/testlist">

    </Spinner>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/new_term"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:hint="New term"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="Some text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/part_of_speech"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:text="Some text">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Part of speech"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/your_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Your name(shown)"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="Some text" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/your_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:text="Some text">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="Some text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2196f3"
        android:text="Suggest"
        android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relation_type"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relation_type"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Для такой верстки уместно использовать корневым контейнером `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Не пользуйтесь графическим редактором - от него одни беды. В вашем случае он проигнорировал часть атрибутов
2. У вас лишние атрибуты у кнопки и она уехала за правый кран экрана. Удалите их

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relation_type"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relation_type"
```

3. InstantRun настройку студии надо выключить и никогда не включать - она работает так плохо, что лучше бы не работал вовсе. Из-за неё часто не видны последние изменения, т.к. приложение не перезапускается полностью.

Comment: Ваш совет мне не помог, к сожалению

Comment: @Asgard, а InstantRun у вас отключен?

Comment: И попробуйте маргин убрать. Может у вас уехало слишком высоко и перекрыто. И включите на девайсе, в настроках разработчика показ границ макета - сможете увидеть что-то, что поможет.

Comment: Margin убирал, инстант включен

Comment: @Asgard, инстант надо выключить и никогда не включать - он работает так плохо, что лучше бы не работал вовсе

Comment: как его выключить?

Comment: @Asgard, нАСТРОЙКИ - `Build execution and deployment`

Comment: все равно это не помогло

Comment: @Asgard, закоментируйте всё в разметке кроме кнопки, включите показ границы макета и выложите скрин в вопрос

Comment: я поторопился, отключив инстант ран она появилась.

Обновите свой ответ, я помечу его как решенный.

Comment: @Asgard, обновил ответ)